# How to Export NDVI image using Fusion Table as featurecollection boundary in GEE python API

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am using python api of google earth engine to create NDVI raster. Now I want to export the raster in my google drive. But during exporting it is giving the following error:

> ee.featurecollection.FeatureCollection object at 0x03D29EF0> is not
>   JSON serializable

I am using the following piece of code for the entire work

```python
import datetime
import ee
import ee.mapclient
import json
from ee.batch import Export
ee.Initialize()

boundary = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1rbhNtC1TqDBvY9Rt2BZR-DjhpIPuC3nU5kmz49WW')

image = (ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').
         filterBounds(boundary).
         filterDate(datetime.datetime(2018,01,24),
                     datetime.datetime(2018,02,28)).
         sort("CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESMENT").
         limit(20))



mosaic = image.mosaic();
cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(10).int();
cirrusBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(11).int();


def maskS2clouds(image): #(
  qa = mosaic.select('QA20');
  #// Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);

cloudMasked = image.filterBounds(boundary).map(maskS2clouds)
median = cloudMasked.median()

clip = median.clip(boundary)

ndvi = clip.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])

task_config = {
    #'image:': ndvi,
    'description': 'PythonExample',
    'scale': 30,  
    'region': boundary
    }


task = ee.batch.Export.image(ndvi, 'nd', task_config)
```

Please help me how I can covert FeatureCollection as json object? My per my understanding from the error I might have to convert the fusion table FeatureCollection into JSON object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a package with some tools for GEE that can be used in this case: [geetools](https://github.com/gee-community/gee_tools)

```python
from geetools import tools

task_config = {
    #'image:': ndvi,
    'description': 'PythonExample',
    'scale': 30,  
    'region': tools.geometry.getRegion(boundary)
    }
```

This should solve it. The function `getRegion` is designed to be used in exporting functions and can manage different situations, so you don't have to worry about that. But if you want to do it without `geetools` this is how:

```python
task_config = {
    #'image:': ndvi,
    'description': 'PythonExample',
    'scale': 30,  
    'region': boundary.geometry().getInfo()['coordinates']
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

boundary = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1rbhNtC1TqDBvY9Rt2BZR-DjhpIPuC3nU5kmz49WW').geometry()

boundary = ee.Geometry(boundary.getInfo()).toGeoJSONString()

Comment: Providing further explanation of your answer would increase the value to users.