# Exporting an image using a FeatureCollection as region in Google Earth Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to export an image using a `FeatureCollection` as region. My code is as follow:

```
params = {
    'description': 'ndviChange_to_gtiff',
    'scale': 30,
    'region': AOI
  }
ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(ndviChange, **params)
```

the AOI is a `FeatureCollection` defined earlier in my code:

```
AOI = ee.FeatureCollection("users/..../AOI")
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Object of type FeatureCollection is not JSON serializable
```

Note that I'm running the code in QGIS GEE plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `getInfo()` to extract the geometry information and then provide that to the region argument.

```
params = {
    'description': 'ndviChange_to_gtiff',
    'scale': 30,
    'region': AOI.geometry().getInfo()['coordinates']
  }
ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(ndviChange, **params)
```

This should be able to solve the issue.

Another solution that I found from [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/302283/33177) is to use `geotools` package and specify the region as:

```
tools.geometry.getRegion(AOI)
```

To upload the results to drive, you also need to start the task. Following snippet starts and logs the task status every 30 seconds:

```
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(ndviChange, **params)
task.start()

## get the status of task while it runs every 30 sec
import time
while task.active():
    time.sleep(30)
    print(task.status())
```

Comment: Thanks @shahryar, that works. But nothing is getting uploaded to my Google Drive. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Edited my answer to show the fix.